# Why shouldn't I bake on scratched silicone mats?

Tags: baking, equipment

My Silpat baking mat came with very clear instructions to throw out the mat as soon as it becomes scratched. It now has a few very light surface scratches that don't seem to have penetrated the first layer of material.

What is the reason it's unsafe (or otherwise undesirable) to use scratched silicone baking mats? Does this vary between different types of silicone cookware?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Silpats and Exopats have a glass fibers (regionally called fiberglass or glass wool, but not candy floss) embedded in them for strength.

The warning not to use them when scratched is because fiber glass does nothing good for a person when ingested, and a scratch may expose it.

Some types of silicone based cookware do not have the fiberglass reinforcement, and so do not have the same issue.  These are mostly the flexible baking dishes or muffin cups, but you should read the label information for the product you have.

Comment: Any idea if this also applies to the generic blue silicone mats? Mine has no stiffness whatsoever so I'd be surprised if it's reinforced with anything other than more silicone, but I don't have the original package to check.

Comment: @Aaronut My guess is no, no but that is just a guess.